# Is this how I need to use the clock() method?

Tags: python, time

Lets say I want that for every second that passes, a point will move 25 pixels on the x axis. Will this work?

```
t=0.0
start=time.clock()
for i in range(10):
    if start>=t+1:
        t+=1
        point.move(25, 0)
```

Comment: Try it and see.  No, it won't work.  Use `time.sleep(1)` to pause for one second.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you show a code of it?

Comment: To do it similarly to how you have it, you should use `time.time()` instead.  `if time.time() - start >= 1: start = time.time() point.move(25, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it two ways: pause for one second using `time.sleep(1)` or check for the amount of time that has passed since `start` was defined.  The first:

```
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    point.move(25, 0)
```

The second:

```
start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    end = time.time()
    if end - start >= 1:
        start = end
        point.move(25, 0)
```

The problem with what you had is that you defined `start` before the `for` loop, but you never changed it again.  Also, I believe that `time.clock()` returns the amount of time that has been spent doing something, but just waiting wouldn't count as time passing.  (I'm not sure on that.)